# Use Javascript on Multiple Divs generated from Database

Tags: javascript, php, html-select

I have a multiselect dropdown menu that needs to be added to each div. The divs will be dynamically created from a database in the future. The problem I am having is that only the first div has a dropdown, the rest are being ignored by the javascript.

How can I loop through the javascript and create an instance for each item like I am doing in the PHP loop?

Thanks!

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function() {

            // 'Select All' text changed
            $("#control_8").multiSelect({ selectAllText: 'Pick all!' });

            // Show test data
            $("FORM").submit( function() {
                $.post('result.php', $(this).serialize(), function(r) {
                    alert(r);
                });
                return false;
            });

        });

    </script>
```

PHP:

```
  <?php

    for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++)
{

 echo"
<select id='control_8' name='control_".$i."[]' multiple='multiple' size='5'>";


        $templates = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM tmpl2");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($templates))
{
    echo "<option value='option_".$row[id]."'>$row[title]</option>";
}


echo "</select>";
}  

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs need to be unique (don't have two selects with the same ID). Add a class to each select, then use the class name to target them all. Using an ID will only select the first one: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

```
$(".somename").multiSelect({ selectAllText: 'Pick all!' });
```